# How to pass multiple variables from Javascript to PHP, using AJAX JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In JS, I got:

```
var UserName;
var MyArray = new Array();

//...filling array

var rqst = new XMLHttpRequest();
rqst.open('POST',"Some.php",true);
rqst.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

What should I write to send UserName and MyArray to PHP file, so I can access them separately. Like:

```
$username = $_POST['JSUserName'];
$array = $_POST['JSArray'];
```

Comment: You can pass as an object.

Comment: you can either pass a query string on the `send` method or a `FormData` object

Comment: I know principes, I need the exact syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As Freddie already stated, you want to define another object with both your `UserName` and `MyArray` values within it:

```
var params = {
  JSUserName: UserName,
  JSArray : myArray
};
```

Then, you can send the whole lot over to your server like so:

```
// This will send the request and yes, the object needs to be stringified!
rqst.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

If you're interested in knowing whether or not the request was successful, you can add something like this as well:

```
// Alert if the call was successful
rqst.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    if (rqst.readyState != 4 || rqst.status != 200) return; 
        alert("Success: " + rqst.responseText); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine them both into a single object and then pass this object in as part of the XHR call.

```
var params = {
  JSUserName: UserName,
  JSArray : myArray
};
```

Comment: I should then:
`
 rqst.send(params);
`
or
`
JSON.stringify(params);
rqst.send(params);
`